# Open Worksheet of Excel File in URL

Tags: c#, .net, apache-flex

I want to open a particular worksheet on a Excel file through URL.  Googling suggested to use this format for the path "http://ags.mydomain.com/MyPMReports/Files/Doc33_HighwaySafety.xls#FreewayCrashRates"

Where Exce File name : Doc33_HighwaySafety.xls
Worksheet inside it : FreewayCrashRates

But this doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

My application is in Flex + .NET

thanks,
capton.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the xls file using [URLLoader](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#load%28%29) as long as the file is in the same domain as your SWF or the server hosting it has a crossdomain.xml file that permits your domain to access it.

The #FreewayCrashRates syntax won't work for xls (in flex at least). You have to parse the xls with some converter ([Google it](http://www.google.com/search?q=xls+to+xml)) before you can use it.

Comment: I think he just wants to open that document in a browser window, from within flex.

Comment: Can you open xls in a browser just like that?

Comment: Yes.  I am just using the 'navigateToURL()' call with the URL as param.